# Infragistics.Controls.Charts.OlapAxis.v11.2 class not found?

Tags: silverlight, infragistics

Hi i am trying to bind pivot grid data with chart in silverlight using infragistics. but i am getting error like this Infragistics.Controls.Charts.OlapAxis.v11.2 class not found. but i am using v11.1 infragistics so it not showing that class to reference so what to do aby other solution to achieve this. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have installed also the version 11.2. If so, then it is possible that you have choosen the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project for references to 11.2 assemblies and if any are found remove that reference and add the 11.1 version of the assembly.  If there are no references to 11.2 in your project, then check any assemblies that you are referencing to see if they contain references to 11.2 and remove change the references to the 11.1 version and recompile.

Comment: Add also the file license.licx to the quest :-)